# Web Scraping with Python (city) as parameter

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, screen-scraping, jython

```
def findWeather(city):
  import urllib

  connection = urllib.urlopen("http://www.canoe.ca/Weather/World.html")
  rate = connection.read()
  connection.close()
  currentLoc = rate.find(city)
  curr = rate.find("currentDegree")
  temploc = rate.find("</span>", curr)
  tempstart = rate.rfind(">", 0, temploc)
  print "current temp:", rate[tempstart+1:temploc]
```

The link is provided above. The issue I have is everytime I run the program and use, say "Brussels" in Belgium, as the parameter, i.e findWeather("Brussels"), it will always print 24c as the temperature whereas (as I am writing this) it should be 19c. This is the case for many other cities provided by the site. Help on this code would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `currentLoc`: you are never using that variable

Comment: You need something like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and/or [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) here. `print` the results in `rate`... you have a massive html response.

Comment: you are finding the `span` tag after finding `currentDegree` which gives the value of first span tag and which is 24.

Comment: curr = rate.find("currentDegree") returns the first located instance in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.canoe.ca/Weather/World.html'
response = requests.get(url)
# Get the text of the contents
html_content = response.text
# Convert the html content into a beautiful soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')
cities = soup.find_all("span", class_="titleText")

cels = soup.find_all("span", class_="currentDegree")

for x,y in zip(cities,cels):
    print (x.text,y.text)
```